# I'm trying to scrape some data from a webpage and keep getting selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException errors

Tags: python, selenium

I've scraped the elements I want from the first page with requests + beautiful soup and am trying to use selenium to click a button that loads another page with the rest of the data I want to scrape. The new selenium window opens the first page, then the second but always returns some sort of selenium.common.exceptions Error.   `File "c:\Users\ArkPr\yelp\yelp_learner.py", line 122, in <module> WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( File "C:\Users\ArkPr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`
I've searched around and tried using implicitly and explicitly wait, time.sleep(), using find_element_by_class_name and xpath, using requests to get the data and I don't know what to do next.

`url = "https://www.yelp.co.uk/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=London&ns=1"`
trying to scrape data from this site

````
next_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name("css-ac8spe")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "css-ac8spe"))
    )
    # element.clear()
    element.click()

except TimeoutException as u:
    print(u)

        # if EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "css-ac8spe")) == True:
# next_page.click()
            # next_page.back()
for li in ul:

    #driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'stickySidebar__373c0__3MPss border-color--default__373c0__r305k')))
    # EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'stickySidebar__373c0__3MPss border-color--default__373c0__r305k')))
    
    
    
    sidebar = driver.find_element_by_class_name('stickySidebar__373c0__3MPss border-color--default__373c0__r305k')
    

    
    if sidebar != None:


        for side in sidebar:
            print(side)
            if side != None:
                try: 


                    address = side.find("p", {"class": " css-chtywg"})
                    # address = side.find_element_by_class_name("css-chtywg")
                    print(address.text)

                except TimeoutException as t:
                    print(t)```
````

Comment: The page pops up a cookie acception modal you need to get rid of first. remember unless you preload the profile, you'll get a clean usersession. Try using ID or XPATH, xpath is the native webdriver elements which may be easier to catch.

Comment: What is the exact data you want to scrape ?

Comment: And I'm just trying to scrape the restaurant's address. what's inside the 'p', {'class': 'css-chtywg'} bit for this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click on more on every post and then, it will naviagte you to the new page, extract the address and come back to original page.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.yelp.co.uk/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=London&ns=1")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
length = len(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'border-color')]/div[contains(@class, 'container')]"))))
j = 0
for i in range(length):
  elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'border-color')]/div[contains(@class, 'container')]")))
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elements[j]).perform()
  time.sleep(1)
  elements[j].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//descendant::a[text()='more']").click()
  time.sleep(1)
  print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.css-chtywg"))).text)
  driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
  time.sleep(2)
  j = j +1
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution kind of works as it does return the address that I was after but after that instead of return more addresses it gives me ```14 North Audley Street London W1K 6WE
Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="/biz/restaurant-gordon-ramsay-london-3?hrid=I9IvzAT4MAv79qt7F8_TFA&amp;osq=Restaurants" class="css-ac8spe">...</a> is not clickable at point (626, 841). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ot-sdk-row">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)``` it repeats that output 4 more times before the program ends.

Comment: Actually never mind your solution works great I just need to make the page scroll down otherwise the program closes early.

Comment: Yeah, it's pointed me on the right track if nothing else and solved the error I ask about so cheers :) using one of the driver.script_execute methods to scroll the page and I think that's that.

Comment: hmmm.. you can edit the post (my answer) with the exact solution that, so it will be easy for future readers, I will approve your changes from my side. cheers !

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.yelp.co.uk/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=London&ns=1")
res_leng = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li/div[contains(@class,'container__09f24')]"))
for i in range(res_leng):
    resturants = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li/div[contains(@class,'container__09f24')]")
    resturants[i].find_element_by_xpath(".//a[text()='more']").click()
    name = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("h1").text
    address = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class=' css-chtywg']").text
    print("{} : {}".format(name,address))
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.back()
```

Comment: This code works really well as well, and I don't seem to need to add any additional code to get it to scroll the page, I'm not understanding why that is.

Comment: Yes, I Myself have this question for a long time.